# How to set up twilio for GAE using Windows7

Tags: google-app-engine, twilio

In the official Google page it shows a linux procedure to set up Twilio for Google App Engine.

What is the procedure for a Windows7 developmente environment?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sms/twilio

There are several linux commands in the preocedure, and I wolud apreciate if somebody can show the Windows7 equivalence for this set up in particular.
The pip installation is the least difficult task, and alredy done

Comment: You'll need to [install pip on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows). I'd also recommend taking a look at this - http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/

Comment: I didn't ask how to install pip. But thanks for your try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twilio help page appears to be clear on this topic: http://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install#installation

> Or, you can download the source code (ZIP) for twilio-python, and then install the library by running:
>      *python setup.py install*
>   in the folder containing the twilio-python library.

So you download the Twilio python library, extract the folder into your google app engine project folder (wherever you're storing your files), then open the cmd prompt for windows, navigate to that directory and run "python setup.py install"

That *should* get things running for you.

Comment: Thanks Kort.It worked very well from a python command line. That's not te problem. What I don't know, is how to tell GAE how to use it, because it throws error telling that it don't know the twilio library. In the Google page are linux commands that I don't know how to replicate in windows.

Comment: If the twilio files are in a folder in your GAE project directory with all your other GAE project files, then GAE should upload the twilio library to the server when you deploy, and then you'll be able to use standard "import module" commands as needed to use the python library in your code. =)

Comment: I've used a similar process for importing pure python modules into my GAE project. However, if there's C compilation requirements, like for the python imaging library, then google will *not* compile it properly on the server and it will not work. It has to be pure python.